# Django queryset filtering out objects with common members

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

Im creating 2-step form. In first part captain is choosing one of his teams, in second i'm retrieving chosen team from first step and creating queryset based on it. Second form should only filter teams that doesn't have players in common with team from first step. Each team has only 3 players.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, unique=True)
    captain = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="captain")
    team_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through="PlayerTeam", related_name="players")

class PlayerTeam(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: I see you have double connection here for Team and Player. You need to leave only one either players = ManyToMany in Team model or player = ForeighKey(Player) for the Team model.

Comment: @SergeyPugach Nope, PlayerTeam is the through model for the ManyToMany between Team and Player (model not shown in question), so this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution without using Q is just to exclude the teams that that have common players.

```
selected_team = Team.objects.get(...) # get selected team
not_allowed_players = selected.team.players.all()
teams = Team.objects.all().exclude(players__in=not_allowed_players)
```

Comment: That worked out, thanks.I'm new to django and didn't think about using __in

Comment: @Nicolas Nice to hear :) Would you mind to accept my answer as solution